# Adonis.js API return mismatch time as compared time in PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: postgresql, adonis.js

Im trying to retrieve data where date time is very important. But the time stored in DB is correct, but it mismatch when I called the API. The date and time stored in DB with data type "timestamptz"

Example of the issue :

```
IN DB -> 2024-02-25 18:00:00.000 +0800
API return -> 2024-02-25T10:00:00.000Z
```

The time in DB is 8 hours ahead than the API return, which the time in DB is the correct one.

I had checked the DB timezone, it's correct as my current location.

Comment: They are the same time. Check the [date time string format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format) of javascript, esp. the last part - Z: the literal `Z`  (in the second version) means the time is in UTC. The value +0800 (in the first version) means it is in the time zone UTC+8 (the offset from UTC is 8 hours)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Serialize it in the Adonis model.

And use timestamp data type in PostgreSQL, instead of timestamptz.

Moreover, remember to add "TZ=UTC" to your .env in Adonis

Example below :

```
  @column.dateTime({
    autoCreate: true,
    serialize: (value: DateTime | null) => {
      return value ? value.setZone('utc').toISO() : value
    },
  })
  public created_at: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({
    autoCreate: true,
    autoUpdate: true,
    serialize: (value: DateTime | null) => {
      return value ? value.setZone('utc').toISO() : value
    },
  })
  public updated_at: DateTime
```

Hope this help for anyone who got this issue.